# How to receive XML data produced by a website?

Tags: .net, xml, api

There is some php API service that when sent some parameters in query string, it returns date in xml format. So I was wondering how to send call the page and get back the result in c# .net. Like with an xml reader or xml scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way is

```
XmlDocument xdoc;
xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(XmlReader.Create("weblink"));
```

The XDocument is not possible to be analyzed and extract its XML values which is possible in XmlDocument

Answer (score 4):

You could pass an url address to [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx):

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("http://example.com/somexml"))
{
    // TODO: parse
}
```

Another possibility is to use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("http://example.com/somexml");
// TODO: manipulate the document
```

And yet another possibility is to use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string xml = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/somexml");
    // TODO: feed the xml to your favorite XML parser
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me whether XDocument.Load will *actually* work with a URI. The documentation suggests it's for *files* rather than URIs, although this would be a bit of a departure.

Comment: @Jon, it works, tested it. Internally the method does exactly what you wrote in your answer with a little addition of a `XmlReaderSettings`.

Comment: Cool... and the parameter name is definitely suggestive, which I'd missed too. Oops :)

Answer (score 3):

If the parameters are in the query string, it's pretty easy... I would use `XmlReader.Create` as per Darin's answer, and then for ease of *working* with the XML, I'd use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("http://example.com/somexml"))
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
}
// Now work with doc
```

(EDIT: As Darin noted, [`XDocument.Load(string uri)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx) makes this simpler - ignore the fact that the docs say it loads the data from a *file*.)

If you need more control over the HTTP side of things (e.g. to include post data) you can use something like:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(...);
// Fiddle with request here

XDocument doc;
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    doc.Load(data);
}
// Use doc here
```

Note that this is all synchronous - parsing it all asynchronously is possible too, but more work.